# Read dataframe split by nan rows and extract specific columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have a example excel file `data2.xlsx` from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5ngschi19ov0rbvqe638b/data2.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=k6trx5gyhtye84k8v6hqqi3iq), which has a `Sheet1` as follows:

[image]

**Preprocess:**

The columns `2018, 2019, 2020, num` are `object` type, which I need to convert to float:

```
cols = ['2018', '2019', '2020', 'num']
df[cols].replace('--', np.nan, regex=True).astype(float)
```

Also I need to extract city names from `bj, sh, gz, sz` from `2019-bj-price-quantity, 2019-sh-price-quantity, 2019-gz-price-quantity, 2019-sz-price-quantity`

```
pattern = '|'.join(['2019-', '-price-quantity'])
df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace(pattern, '')
```

Finally I need to extract `price` and `quantity` of `num`s for each city and reshape a new dataframe like this:

[image]

How could I do that in pandas? Thanks.

**Update:**

```
df = pd.read_excel('./data2.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1', header = None)
df.groupby(df.iloc[:, 0].isna().cumsum()).transform('first')
```

Out:

```
                         0       1       2       3    4
0   2019-bj-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
1   2019-bj-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
2   2019-bj-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
3   2019-bj-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
4   2019-sh-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
5   2019-sh-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
6   2019-sh-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
7   2019-sh-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
8   2019-sh-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
9                      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
10  2019-gz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
11  2019-gz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
12  2019-gz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
13  2019-gz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
14  2019-gz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
15                     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
16  2019-sz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
17  2019-sz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
18  2019-sz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
19  2019-sz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
20  2019-sz-price-quantity  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0  num
```

Reference related: [Read dataframe split by nan rows and reshape them into multiple dataframes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245428/read-dataframe-split-by-nan-rows-and-reshape-them-into-multiple-dataframes-in-py?noredirect=1#comment111837699_63245428)

Comment: Please check the reference link in the end of my question, jezrael has provided cool solution to read `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code based on jezrael's great answer, welcome to share better solution or improve it:

```
# add header=None for default columns names
df = pd.read_excel('./data2.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1', header=None)

# convert columns by second row
df.columns = df.iloc[1].rename(None)

# create new column `city` by forward filling non missing values by second column
df.insert(0, 'city', df.iloc[:, 0].mask(df.iloc[:, 1].notna()).ffill())

pattern = '|'.join(['2019-', '-price-quantity'])
df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace(pattern, '')
df['year'] = df['year'].str.replace(pattern, '')
# convert floats to integers 
df.columns = [int(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x for x in df.columns]
df = df[df.year.isin(['price', 'quantity'])]
df = df[['city', 'year', 'num']]
df['num'] = df['num'].replace('--', np.nan, regex=True).astype(float)
df = df.set_index(['city', 'year']).unstack().reset_index()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df.rename({'year': 'city'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Out:

```
year      price  quantity
0     bj   21.0      10.0
1     gz    6.0      15.0
2     sh   12.0       NaN
3     sz   13.0       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

*note I use column indices when the column name is not certain

You can split tables with

```
df['city'] = df.groupby(df.iloc[:, 0].isna().cumsum()).transform(first)
df.dropna(subset=df.columns[0], inplace=True)
df = df.loc[df[df.colmns[0]] != df.city]
```

Now `df` will have an additional column `city` with the table title, while the title and empty rows have been discarded. You can access any part of that `city` column with `.str.split.str.get`

```
df.city = df.city.str.split('-').str.get(1)
```

Finally you want to keep just the `num` column, which is the easiest step

```
df = df.iloc[:, [0, 4, 5]]
df = df.pivot(index='city', columns=df.columns[0], values=df.columns[1])
```

Comment: Did you get it to work? I didn't test it and there could be a bug. Here's the docs for first https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html

Comment: I add `''` on `first`, it works. I also update the result from your first line of code, it seems we can't assign it as `df['city']`.